# php foreach table display on multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array that im trying to get to out put a table like this [image: just hardcoded example of what I want], using the foreach method. I get the array to string conversion error, and I've been playing around with it for a bit now can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
$DogToys = array();
  $DogToys[0] = array("collar","14.99","red", "smooth");
  $DogToys[1] = array("Bow","4.99","pink", "silky");
  $DogToys[2] = array("booties","24.99","green", "smooth");
  $DogToys[3] = array("Tail Bow","5.99","pink", "Satin");
  $DogToys[4] = array("ear clip","7.99","green", "plastic");

?>

    <h5>Accessories For Sale -- Well Worth a Second Look!</h5>
                    <?php
                    echo "<table>";
                    foreach($DogToys as $accesories) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$accesories."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<br >";
                    }       
                    echo "</table>";
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$DogToys` array is a multidimensional array. When you use:

```
foreach($DogToys as $accessories) {
...
}
```

each `$accessories` is *also* an array -- an array within your array.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$DogToys = array();
  $DogToys[0] = array("collar","14.99","red", "smooth");
  $DogToys[1] = array("Bow","4.99","pink", "silky");
  $DogToys[2] = array("booties","24.99","green", "smooth");
  $DogToys[3] = array("Tail Bow","5.99","pink", "Satin");
  $DogToys[4] = array("ear clip","7.99","green", "plastic");

?>

    <h5>Accessories For Sale -- Well Worth a Second Look!</h5>
                    <?php
                    echo "<table>";
                    foreach($DogToys as $accesories) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$accesories[0]."</td>
                          <td>".$accesories[1]."</td>
                          <td>".$accesories[2]."</td>
                          <td>".$accesories[3]."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<br >";
                    }       
                    echo "</table>";
                    ?>
```

Alternately, you could apply what you did to the outer array (`$DogToys`) to each inner array (`$accessories`):

```
    <h5>Accessories For Sale -- Well Worth a Second Look!</h5>
                    <?php
                    echo "<table>";
                    foreach($DogToys as $accesories) {
                      echo "<tr>";
                        foreach ($accessories as $item) {
                            echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
                        }
                      echo "</tr>";
                      echo "<br >";
                    }       
                    echo "</table>";
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need another loop as it's multi-dimensional:

```
<?php
$DogToys = array();
  $DogToys[0] = array("collar","14.99","red", "smooth");
  $DogToys[1] = array("Bow","4.99","pink", "silky");
  $DogToys[2] = array("booties","24.99","green", "smooth");
  $DogToys[3] = array("Tail Bow","5.99","pink", "Satin");
  $DogToys[4] = array("ear clip","7.99","green", "plastic");

?>

<h5>Accessories For Sale -- Well Worth a Second Look!</h5>
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>"; //to match your imaage
foreach ($DogToys as $each){

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($each as $accesories){
        echo "<td>" . $accesories . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```